# Aggregating data with 2 columns in data.table (r language)

Tags: r

I have my table(input):

```
date         directorName      companyName  rank
2015-08-01   Sergey            vino          29
2015-08-02   Sergey            vino          42
2015-08-09   Sergey            vino          25
2015-08-04   Sergey            vino          27
2015-08-05   Mike              bolder        29
2015-08-01   Mike              bolder        27
2015-08-11   Mike              bolder        23
2015-08-09   Mike              bolder        30
2015-08-09   Jay               bolder        2
2015-08-10   Jay               bolder        10
2015-08-11   Jay               bolder        31
```

I want to know  `directorName` who reached top 30 in `rank` but from `companyName` who never reached top 10. Output:

```
    date         directorName      companyName  rank
    2015-08-01   Sergey            vino          29
    2015-08-02   Sergey            vino          42
    2015-08-09   Sergey            vino          25
    2015-08-04   Sergey            vino          27
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try this in a two-step process using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'companyName' `if` `all` the 'rank' is greater than 10 we Subset the Data.table (`.SD`) (in the current example this gives the expected output).   In the second step, we group by 'directorName', check `if` `any` elements of 'rank' is greater than 30, then we Subset again.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(all(rank > 10)) .SD, companyName][, if(any(rank >30)) .SD , directorName]

#   companyName       date directorName rank
#1:        vino 2015-08-01       Sergey   29
#2:        vino 2015-08-02       Sergey   42
#3:        vino 2015-08-09       Sergey   25
#4:        vino 2015-08-04       Sergey   27
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original data is in a data table called DT:

```
library(data.table)
output <- DT[ rank > 10 & rank <= 30, ]
```

Comment: This would select Mike, even though the company *bolder* has reached the top 10 in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The first command finds all the companies that never reached top 10:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(companyName) %>% 
    summarise(min = min(rank)) %>% 
    filter(min > 10) %>% select(companyName) -> tt
```

The second selects the directors in the top 30. `unique` is there simply
to avoid repetition:

```
unique(df$directorName[df$companyName %in% tt$companyName & df$rank < 30])
```

Output:

```
"Sergey"
```